# Download last maven snapshot from artifactory

Tags: java, maven, artifactory, snapshot

I know there is a way to request an endpoint and download the lastest Maven Snapshot from Artifactory because this [JIRA Ticket](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-4855) says that JFrog people resolved it, but I can't find anywhere the exact syntax of the URL. (The URL in the ticket doesn't work)

Does anybody knows how to download the lastest Maven Snapshot for a given module via endpoint (not via script, only requesting the endpoint)?

I need to download de .tar.gz package.

Comment: I doubt there is a URL for getting the latest. Instead, you could do through the special tag `<version>LATEST</version>` in your pom, and them run `mvn dependency:get` to download it. Wouldn't it be useful for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To download the latest Maven **unique snapshot** version of an artifact from Artifactory you should use the following

```
http://localhost:8080/artifactory/<REPO-KEY>/<GROUPD-ID>/<ARTIFACT-ID>/<VERSION>-SNAPSHOT/<ARTIFACT-ID>-<VERSION>-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Where:

- REPO-KEY - the Artifactory repository key (identifier)
- GROUP-ID - maven groupdId (delimited by /)
- ARTIFACT-ID - maven artifactId
- VERSION - maven version

For example:

> http://localhost:8080/artifactory/libs-release-local/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/0.9.9-SNAPSHOT/logback-classic-0.9.9-SNAPSHOT.jar

To download the latest **release** artifact you should use `[RELEASE]` as the version, for example:

> http://localhost:8080/artifactory/ivy-local/org/acme/[RELEASE]/acme-[RELEASE].jar

For more info see the Artifactory REST API [documentation](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-RetrieveLatestArtifact)